# recursion method Stack Overflow error

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

In my code i am just trying to make a simple program that tells you if one number can divide into another number evenly (in this case that number is 3). right now I am saying that if x (the number doesnt divide evenly add 0.01 to it, that gives me the stack overflow error. If I make the value 0.2 it says that 9 is a divisible of three when really the next thing number that divides into three after three is 6

```
public class divisible {

   public static void divide(double x) {
      double three = 3;
      double value = x%three;

      if (value==0) {
         System.out.println(x + " is a divisible of 3 ");
         return;
      }else{ 
         //System.out.println("x does not divide evenly into 3");
         divide(x+(.01));
      }

   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      divide(4);
   }
}
```

Comment: System.out.println(x); could you try this in your else statement? It would help you to determine what x is along the way and see if it ever becomes 6.

Comment: It is very redundant to have a variable named `three` and to assign `3` to it. You should have a meaningful name, and make it a class variable.

Answer (score 3):

The reason the recursion is infinite is a little obscure: the `0.1` cannot be represented exactly in `double`. When you add `0.1` to `3` ten times, you do *not* get a `4` - you get a number that's close to `4`, but a little greater than it. That number does not divide your target evenly, so the recursion goes on to `4.1`, `4.2`, and so on, with no end.

The reason is the same why this loop never stops ([try it!](http://ideone.com/w2Fk6n)):

```
for (double x = 3 ; x != 4 ; x += 0.1) {
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Using [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) in place of `double` would fix the problem, because `0.1` would be represented exactly. Of course it would still print a wrong message (the `"is divisible of 3"` is hard-coded, even though `x` could be an entirely different number in the invocation when the remainder becomes zero).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you compare two doubles with `==`. This will produce unreliable results, due to the way that floating point arithmetic is implemented. Your method should look like this:

```
public static void divide(int x) {
  int three = 3;
  int value = x%three;

  if (value==0) {
     System.out.println(x + " is a divisible of 3 ");
     return;
  }else{ 
     System.out.println("x does not divide evenly into 3");
//         divide(x+(.01));
  }

}
```

If you want the method to be accessed with a double argument, you can cast:

```
public static void divide(double x) {
    x = (int) Math.round(x);
```

If you want to be able to handle number larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, you can use `BigInteger`